# Как вставлять изображения для gmail в HTML?

Tags: html, css

никак не могу понять почему не вставляется изображение в html (а точнее не отображается в gmail) тоисть изображение просто вырезается.

Пробовал вставлять ссылку, b64 - и то и другое вырезается http://prntscr.com/jc3kpx .

Вот так подгружаю изображение:

```
<p style="background-image: url(some b64 or url)"></p>
```

Научите вставлять, пожалуйста ;)

Comment: background: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8, <svg></svg>');

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте вставить картинку тегом `<img>`

Comment: Проблема видимо в формате изображения (svg), jpg подгрузило